# How to put a conditional statement inside of a filter in java

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a rather obnoxious command that will throw a null pointer exception part way through a filter.  It looks like so:

```
someObject.getAttributes().stream().filter(
    attr -> attr.getAllValues().getValue().stream().filter(
    rule -> "some rule".equals(value.getType())).findFirst().isPresent())
    .forEach(this::visit);
```

The "this::visit" calls a local method for each value.  The issue occurs with the getAttributes() method.  It can return null, thus throwing a null pointer when getValue() is called.  What I want is for the getValue() (and everything after) is only called if getAllValues() is not null.  What I'm assuming needs to happen is the

```
attr -> attr.getAllValues()
```

needs to have some conditional statement, like:

```
attr -> attr.getAllValues() ? return : attr.getAllValues().getValue()...
```

Is there a way to do this?  Or some kind of method that takes care of this?

Comment: `.filter(...).findFirst().isPresent()` can be replaced with `anyMatch(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `attr.getAllValues()` call can return null, which causes `getValue()` to throw a NPE.

If that's the case, why not filter it twice? The first filter to remove all attributes that return a null on `getAllValues`, and the second with what you currently have.